# How to maintain the map state in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using a MapView with a default location. If I go to another location on the map and then change the orientation of the device, the orientation does not save my previous location. It starts from the default location!

How can I avoid this? I do not want to disable the screen-oreintation change for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to save the location and then use `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` in `onCreate()` to restore the selected item.

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return mapView.getMapCenter();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    Geopoint center = (Geopoint) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

    if (point != null)
        mapView.getController().animateTo(center);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the application now crashes when I rotate the screen.

This is what I use:

Override public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {     return myMapView } 

and ...

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     GeoPoint point = (GeoPoint) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();   
   if (point != null)     
    myMapView ().animateTo(point); 
} 

Please advise..

Comment: you dont want to return the whole map view! Just the map center. When the orientation changes the map view will be destroyed and reconstructed. I updated my code which makes my answer clearer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid that I didn't quite explain my question correctly. On rotating the screen, the user is supposed to be still on his earlier location. But at the moment, the user is being redirected to the default location that I had set.

Eg: 
Default Location: Detroit --> New Location: Seattle -->Rotate Screen --> User should still be on Seattle.
But is being shown back on Detroit.

Nonetheless, thank you for your updated answer. I look forward to any suggestion to my question.